# How to compare the frequencies by multiple groups?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, frequency

Here are my data. Each row represents a sample and different VAR mean different component.

```
> df
     VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5 VAR6 VAR7 VAR8  Group
ACSK   16    4    0   25    0    0    7   16 Group3
CKPD    9   19    0   17    0   11    6   13 Group3
AEXF   10    0    0   36    0    0    0    0 Group1
AGNS   34    0   77   30    0    0    0    0 Group3
AGRL   19    0    0   52    0    0    0    0 Group2
AJEH    5    0   40    8    0    0    0   13 Group3
AOKS   34    0   47   43    0    0    0    0 Group2
AYKR   14    0  186   18    0    0    0    0 Group2
MIEY   20  226    0  102    0    0  201    0 Group1
BLHR   13    0    0   50    0    0    0    0 Group1
```

I want to compare the frequency distribution of different `VARs` among different `Groups`. Can I just sum the number by row for those of the same group and then apply the chisq test? Or any other statistical method?

Comment: What do your rows represent? Why do you have multiple rows of the same group? What are the row names?

Comment: @user2974951 Hi. I have edited my question. Each row represents a sample and different VAR mean different component. Thats why the same group have multiple rows.